# What if I can't comment on a wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

I have read an answer to a question, which is subtly wrong, but was upvoted possibly for the nice explanation. Now I don't have the rep to comment on the answer, and I don't want to down vote it either because well, again I don't have the rep and, worse, no one learns anything this way.

I tried to edit the answer to clarify where the author went wrong, but my suggested edit was rejected. I wasn't aware that those sort of "comment-like" edits were not acceptable. Just to point out, the suggested edit was rejected by the difference of just 1 vote, meaning that there were some voters who actually saw the point of it.

I'm trying here again on meta just to get my point across. The answer I'm referring to is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15321852/1159107 I don't want to down-vote, just a simple comment explaining that the exponent's sign is not done by a sign-bit but actually done by biasing, and so 111 is actually a valid (4) and not (infinity).

Was there something simpler I could have done but I just missed it?

Comment: You have 49 reputation on Stack Overflow.  Just **1** more and you can leave comments on any post.

Comment: Suggest an edit on a different question..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep the answer in your bookmarks (or bookmark the question by clicking on the star below the score), accumulate enough reputation for commenting (you only need 50, it's very easy for someone serious), after you've got enough reputation, return to the answer and comment.

*Don't* use:

- Flags (moderators won't handle technical innacuracies, don't try).
- Edit suggestions (to tell the OP about the fault. Correcting it is OK)

**Edit: You now have the comment everywhere privilege!**

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If an answer is wrong and somebody hasn't already provided the correct answer, you can respond by **answering the question**.  In your answer you can explain the subtleties; you don't need to call out the other answer explicitly, but you can say something like "it might seem that you could do X, but that would cause problem Y".

If your answer is correct and well-explained then it should attract upvotes.  This helps you get the comment privilege, but more importantly, it improves the content on the site.